# How do i fix, bad object refs/remotes/origin/master?

Tags: git, synchronization, git-merge, git-commit

> git pull --tags origin master
> fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/master

please help me fix, i've trying to commit been trying to commit ans sync my changes

commit and sync, after working on few files in my project i cant commit my code.

Comment: Please provide more information. This is way too broad.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.